# Kotlin with Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

```
    var bundle : Bundle ? =null

    bundle?.putString("text",text)

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        frag = Fragment.instantiate(context,Fragment2::class.java.name) as Fragment2
    }

    frag?.arguments=bundle

    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentPanel1,frag).commit()
```

I Have written these code on fragment1 and passing the data to it

On Fragment 2 I am receving the bundle as null can anyone solve it

```
var bundle : Bundle ?
bundle = arguments

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    Toast.makeText(context,bundle.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

Comment: Where do you actually set `bundle` to anything other than null in fragment1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue is that you don't initialize var of bundle.look below.

```
val bundle = Bundle()

bundle.putString("text",text)

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    frag = Fragment.instantiate(context,Fragment2::class.java.name) as Fragment2
}

frag?.arguments=bundle

fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentPanel1,frag).commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below code

```
 /**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @return A new instance of fragment ProfileFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
@JvmStatic
fun newInstance(bundle: Bundle) = ProfileFragment().apply { arguments 
= bundle }
}

startFragment(ProfileFragment.newInstance(Bundle()))
```